# How to make tabs in ionic without using <ion-tabs> in ionic1

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I need to create 5 tabs with different styles. The problem is that if I use `<ion-tabs>`, any changes I make to a single tab will be reflected to all 5 of my tabs. Are there any other options besides `<ion-tabs>`?

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
    <!-- lobby Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Lobby"  icon="icon ion-android-list" href="#/main/fixture">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-fixture"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <!-- upcomming Tab badge="3" badge-style="badge-assertive"-->
    <ion-tab title="Upcoming"  icon="ion-android-globe trans"   href="#/main/live">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-live"></ion-nav-view>1
    </ion-tab>
    <!-- score Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Scores"  icon="icon ion-social-dribbble-outline" href="#/main/result">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-result"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <!-- friend Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Friends" icon="icon ion-help-buoy" href="#/main/friend">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-friend"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <!-- Amount Tab -->
    <ion-tab title="Amount" icon="ion-android-globe trans"  href="#/main/amount1">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-amount"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the code so that it is easier to read, and changed the wording of the question to be more concise and to the point. This will help people who are trying to answer your question to focus on your question.